# Find coefficient of generating function f(x).

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find coefficient of generating function.

$ f(x) = \frac{2x}{1-x^{2}} +x$

---

MY WAY OF SOLVING SIMILAR PROBLEM:

1) $ g(x) = \frac{2x}{1-x^{2}}$

2) partial fraction $g(x) = \frac{A}{1-x} + \frac{B}{1+x} $

3) $ g(x) =  \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty Ax^{n} + \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty B (-1)^nx^{n} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (A+(-1)^nB)x^{n} $ -solution

But what can I do with $f(x)$? I can't use my method because:

$f(x) = \frac{2x+x(1-x^2)}{1-x^2} $

$\frac{-x^3 +3x}{1-x^2} = \frac{A}{1-x} + \frac{B}{1+x}$

$ -x^3+3x = A(1+x) + B(1-x) $

$-x^3 = 0 \cdot x^3  $

$ -1 =0 $

Comment: Do the same, just don't mix the standalone $x$ into the fraction.

Comment: Partial fractions – that's the hard way to do $g$. It's just a geometric series. And for $f$, partial fractions only works when degree of numerator less than degree of denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to add up the right hand terms, since the term $x$ is simple and convenient. The other term can be expanded using the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* expansion
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n\qquad\qquad |y|<1
\end{align*}
with $y=x^2$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)&=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}+x\\
> &=2x\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}+x\\
> &=3x+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n+1}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude the coefficient $[x^n]$ of $f(x)$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 3&n=1\\
> 2&n>1, odd\\
> 0&n\geq 0, even
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}